# How to execute new project file in mongoDb tutorial point online terminal

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to execute the queries from the .mdb file in tutorial point online mongo db terminal, but couldn't find the way. Can anyone please help me on this.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb_terminal_online.php

Please refer the above url.

Answer (score 0):

it is functions, you need to use terminal, I checked, it is working, write `show dbs;` it will show result.

Comment: Yes is working if we give command in terminal. But i want to know is there any way to execute the query from the  newfile.mdb?

Comment: Better you use your local machine. install mongo on your local machine with few line of code and try the terminal.